# PIT implies: In a boolean lattice, every filter can be enlarged to a maximal one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra, filters, proof-explanation

I am working through this proof of [Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice*](https://books.google.de/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&lpg=PR3&ots=HKTfWKteWS&dq=herrlich%20axiom%20of%20choice&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

$(1)\Rightarrow(2)$: How do you define the quotient lattice $B$ modulo a Filter? And why is the preimage of the maximal filter $\mathcal{G}$ maximal in $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean lattice has a complement operation. So you can define what would be a symmetric difference, $a\oplus b=(a\lor b)-(a\land b)$. Now $a\equiv_\cal F b$ if and only if $1-(a\oplus b)\in\cal F$.

This is just like the usual quotient by a filter, or usually an ultrafilter. Or an ideal in ring theory. You want two things to be identified if their difference is negligible.

Verifying that the preimage of a maximal filter in $B/\cal F$ is an extension of $\cal F$ to a maximal filter is just verifying the definitions, and I will leave this part to you. Unless you have a specific point you wish clarified.

Comment: I tried showing, that $f^{-1}[\mathcal{G}]$ is maximal but I failed: Suppose this Filter is not maximal, then there is a strictly larger filter $\mathcal{H}$. Then, I could take $x \in \mathcal{H}\setminus f^{-1}[\mathcal{G}]$ and look at $f(x)$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Show that $\cal H/F$ extends $\cal G$.